# Is there a way to ssh with qpython?

Tags: python, qpython

I have run into errors trying to pip install fabric, or paramiko (results in a pycrypto install RuntimeError: chmod error).

Is there a way to ssh from within a qpython script?

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that you can't install `pycrypto`,
try `pycryptodome-qpython3` from QPyPI on QPython3L.
Right now, the only working package similar to `pycrypto` is `pycryptodome-qpython3` on QPyPI.
And it only works on QPython3L.

- [QPyPI pycryptodome-qpython3](https://qpypi3.qpython.org/pyshop/package/pycryptodome-qpython3)
- [QPyPI file pycryptodome-qpython3-3.8.1.tar.gz](http://pypi3.qpython.org/repository/129423/pycryptodome-qpython3-3.8.1.tar.gz#6b29d6800113433924b1afeadc986fab)

(I shared a Crypto.zip on Google drive before.
That's an ancient pycrypto 2.5, working on ancient Python 2, on ancient QPython v1.3.2.
I don't think any people would still need the ancient version.)

Answer (score 1):

U need a compiler to build the cryptography module, and it is not included. The best option is to get the cross compiler then build the module yourself. I don't see any prebuilt module for QPython about ssh/paramiko.

Maybe u can try out other libs, busybox/ssh or maybe dropbear for arm.

**Update**

I've take a proper look at the QPython modules, and both OpenSSL and SSH are preinstalled. You don't need to install them.

Still having problem with the Crypto module. I can't understand how much usefull is the ssh module without the Cryto one ... omg.

**Update 2**

Tried the Qpypi lib manager, found the cryptography on list, but at time of install didn't found it. Couldn't believe how much difficult is to put ssh to work with QPython.